# Why is the compiler saying my integer variable is not being used?

Tags: c++, stream, compiler-warnings

I am receiving a warning saying that my int variable is unused but I am using it to store a integer value from a text file that I am reading in.

**Warning message**:

```
menu.cpp:48:6: warning: unused variable ‘Release_year’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int Release_year;
```

**menu.cpp**:

```
void Menu::LoadMovies(string filename)
{
    ifstream file;
    string line;
    string myString;

    string Movie_title, Lead_actor_actress, Description;
    int Release_year;

    file.open(filename.c_str());

    if (!file)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, Movie_title, ',');
        getline(ss, Lead_actor_actress, ',');
        getline(ss, Description, ',');
        //Edit
        cin >> Release_year;
        //getline(ss, myString, ',');       //reading in the integer as a string for purpose of getline
        //Release_year = stoi(myString);   //converting it to an integer

    }

    file.close();

}
```

Is my syntax for reading in and converting the variable wrong? I get what the warning is for and saying but what could be causing this warning?

Answer (score 4):

You assign to `Release_year` but you never read it.

Thus it is unused.

You do work to generate its value, but discard it.

Doing pointless work and never consuming it is often a bug.  So the compiler has a warning that says "warning, you have a variable you never used".

Comment: Like I said, I get why the compiler has that warning. It basically is what it says. I removed my last two statements in the loop and instead just put cin >> Release_year; ..... thank you for your reply my friend

Comment: If it helps, my understanding is that somewhere else in your code you use the other variables `Movie_title`, `Lead_actor_actress`, etc. to perform some kind of work (writing to a file, printing to the console, or something of the like) but with `Release_year` you do not.

Comment: @xcyb that change suppresses the ability for the compiler to detect the mistake, but doesn't eliminate the problem.  Do **not** treat warnings as something to get rid of; instead they are telling you your code has a mistake.  Find the mistake; why are you reading data then discarding it?  If you want to suppress the error, add a comment, then type `(void)Release_year;`, which every compiler treats as a "no, I want to discard this".